# Neural Network Cost function returning Nan in Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, octave

I am  working on a NN and trying to generate learning and validation curves.

This is my vectorized cost function

```
sum(sum((-Y).*log(h) - (1-Y).*log(1-h), 2))/m + lambda*p/(2*m);
```

However the validation error returns Nan  when i train the parameters on small training set sizes before calculating the validation error.

This is the code I am trying to implement:

```
function [error_train, error_val, m] = ...
learningCurve(input_layer_size,hidden_layer_size,num_labels,X, y, Xval, yval, lambda)
% returns the train and
% cross validation set errors for a learning curve.
% Number of training examples
m = size(X,1);

% You need to return these values correctly
error_train = zeros(m, 1);
error_val   = zeros(m, 1);


for i = 1:m
    nn_params = trainNeural(input_layer_size, hidden_layer_size, num_labels,X(1:i, :), y(1:i), lambda); 
    [error_train(i), grad] = nnCostFunction(nn_params, ...
                                   input_layer_size, ...
                                   hidden_layer_size, ...
                                   num_labels, ...
                X(1:m), :), y(1:m), 0);

    [error_val(i), grad] = nnCostFunction(nn_params, ...
                                   input_layer_size, ...
                                   hidden_layer_size, ...
                                   num_labels, ...
                   Xval, yval,0);
end
```

Comment: You say adding a small term inside your log functions affected things badly - what exactly happened?

Comment: First, are you sure about the first `-Y`? Second, usually one uses the fact that `0*log(0)` approaches zero and defines `0*log(0) =: 0`. Thus, only one of the `log` terms is used per sample, the other one is ignored.

Comment: A relevant question is why would h be exactly 0 or 1? What is the underlying model? If it's logistic regression (which I suspect it is), does that mean your underlying (theta' * x) term is _actual_ +/- infinity at any point?

Comment: @RoyMak it's returning nan values because presumably you end up in a zero times infinity scenario. You can treat this as a special case, detect it, and replace this with zero. But the question is why are you getting this scenario in the first place. You probably shouldn't.

Comment: @cheersmate is my implementation of the cost function not correct? I am still new to machine learning so any feedback will be appreciated. I tried this implementation to avoid the NAN output caused by 0*log(0): cost = sum(sum(-log(htheta(y == 1))) + sum(-log(1 - htheta(y == 0))))/m ; however the cross validation error is outputting as inifity. Could someone help me with the correct implementation of the cost function so as to not get Inf or Nan outputs from my neural network cost function

Comment: My main problem now  is the cross validation error . when i am training coming up with the errors to plot the learning curve. When i train parameters on small training set sizes to calculate the cross validation error i am getting as an output Inf or Nan for the cross validation error